# Why does Travis fail running tests for some-but-not-all my target destinations?

Tags: ios, travis-ci, xcodebuild

I'm using Travis for the continuous integration of my open source project [`BSGUtilities`](https://github.com/Bootstragram/BSGUtilities).
My build there fails for the following reason:

> Scheme BSGUtilities is not currently configured for the test action.

It actually is configured for the test action: I run it fine locally and the scheme is present on Git.

What's really weird is that I'm running the same tests on 3 different xcodebuild destinations and I get different results:

- `iPhone 6s,OS=9.3`: the build fails with the error above
- `iPhone 7,OS=10.0`: tests run fine and the command succeeds
- `iPhone 8,OS=11.2`: the build fails with the error above

Any idea what goes wrong here and why Travis can run my tests fine with some destinations and not others?

Here is my `.travis.yml`:

```
# references:
# * http://www.objc.io/issue-6/travis-ci.html
# * https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty#usage

osx_image: xcode9.2
language: objective-c
# before_install: cd Example && pod install && cd -
podfile: Example/Podfile

before_install:
  - bundle install
  - bundle exec pod repo update
  - bundle exec pod install --project-directory=Example
  - instruments -s devices

script:
  - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace Example/BSGUtilities.xcworkspace -scheme BSGUtilities -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s,OS=9.3' test | xcpretty
  - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace Example/BSGUtilities.xcworkspace -scheme BSGUtilities -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=10.0' test | xcpretty
  - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace Example/BSGUtilities.xcworkspace -scheme BSGUtilities -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=11.2' test | xcpretty
  - pod lib lint --allow-warnings
```

The Travis output is available here: https://travis-ci.org/Bootstragram/BSGUtilities/builds/342350211